# React-Router showing error page when going directly to nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

When I enter URL to a blog post (like: localhost/blog/clothing-article) for half a second I'm seeing my Error 404 page and after that the blog post. How can I prevent this?

The way I understand this "issue" is that the switch is triggered before the rendering of the nested-route/my blog item component (duuh). Also don't like the idea to load all existing blog posts paths in the main, so the switch knows about them.

My current setup:
Main.tsx

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="main">
    <Header />
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
       <Route path='/portfolio' component={Portfolio} />
       <Route path='/about' component={About} />
       <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
       <Route component={ErrorPage} />
    </Switch>
    <BackTop />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And my blog.tsx with the section to show the blog item

```
<div>
   {this.props.match && this.props.match.isExact &&
     <ul className={styles.blog}>
       {blogPosts.length > 0 &&
           postElements
       }
     </ul>
   }
   {this.props.match && !this.props.match.isExact &&
      <Route 
        path={`${this.props.match.url}/:slug`} 
        render={(props) => <BlogItem allPostData={blogPosts} {...props} />} />
   }
</div>
```

Comment: Not to load all paths but, Have you tried adding the url parameter :slug to the main route? You can access the slug variable via props
`<Route path='/blog/:slug' component={Blog} />`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it was though week. I get your idea - this will kinda register the nested route, right? But wouldn't it change the logic? Inside the Blog component (and route) I'm generating the nested route for a blog post. Maybe I'm not implementing it the best way?